# Find the owning Part of a node element with docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

I've got a list of placeholders in my DOCX document I've referenced this way :

```
private void findPlaceHolders() {
    Docx4JPlaceHolderFinder finder = new Docx4JPlaceHolderFinder();
    TraversalUtil.visit(document, false, finder);
    placeHoldersRegister = new HashMap<>(finder.getFoundPlaceHolders());
}
```

`Docx4JPlaceHolderFinder` is an implementation of `CallbackImpl`, finding all `ContentAccessor` (mostly `R`) instance containing text value of this form : **$[placeholder_name]**.

`placeHolderRegister` is an instance of `HashMap<String, List<ContentAccessor>>` ; it associates lists of `ContentAccessor` instances with their corresponding placeholder keyword.

I want to be able to insert picture in those placeholders. Here is the complete source code of my `Docx4JImageMailMerger` class :

```
package org.johndoe.fwk.simplefile.implementation.docxutil;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.docx4j.TraversalUtil;
import org.docx4j.dml.wordprocessingDrawing.Inline;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.Part;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.BinaryPartAbstractImage;
import org.docx4j.wml.ContentAccessor;
import org.docx4j.wml.Drawing;
import org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory;

import org.johndoe.fwk.exception.ExceptionFwk;

/**
 * Classe dédiée au publipostage d'image dans un document Docx4J.
 */
public class Docx4JImageMailMerger {

    private final ObjectFactory factory;
    private WordprocessingMLPackage document;
    private Map<String, List<ContentAccessor>> placeHoldersRegister;

    public Docx4JImageMailMerger(WordprocessingMLPackage document) {
        this.factory = new ObjectFactory();
        this.document = document;
    }

    public void setImage(String placeHolderName, File imageFile) {
        setImage(placeHolderName, imageFile, null);
    }

    public void setImage(String placeHolderName, File imageFile, Long width) {
        List<ContentAccessor> placeHolders = selectPlaceHolders(placeHolderName);

        for (ContentAccessor placeHolder : placeHolders) {
            cleanPlaceHolder(placeHolder);
            includeImage(placeHolder, imageFile, width);
        }
    }

    private List<ContentAccessor> selectPlaceHolders(String imageName) {
        if (placeHoldersRegister == null)
            findPlaceHolders();

        List<ContentAccessor> selectedPlaceHolders = new ArrayList<>();
        selectedPlaceHolders.addAll(placeHoldersRegister.get(imageName));
        return selectedPlaceHolders;
    }

    private void findPlaceHolders() {
        Docx4JPlaceHolderFinder finder = new Docx4JPlaceHolderFinder();
        TraversalUtil.visit(document, false, finder);
        placeHoldersRegister = new HashMap<>(finder.getFoundPlaceHolders());
    }

    private void cleanPlaceHolder(ContentAccessor placeHolder) {
        placeHolder.getContent().clear();
    }

    private void includeImage(ContentAccessor placeHolder, File imageFile, Long width) {
        try {
            Part part = getOwningPart(placeHolder);
            BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(document, part, imageFile);

            Inline inline;
            if (width == null)
                inline = imagePart.createImageInline(imageFile.getName(), "test", 0, 1, false);
            else
                inline = imagePart.createImageInline(imageFile.getName(), "test", 0, 1, width, false);

            Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
            drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inline);
            placeHolder.getContent().add(drawing);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionFwk("Erreur lors de l'inclusion de l'image", e);
        }
    }

    private Part getOwningPart(ContentAccessor placeHolder) {
        // What should I do here ?
    }

}
```

I don't know in which part of my document is the selected placeholder : body, header, footer, etc. The problem is I must determine it for `BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(document, part, imageFile)`.

Is there any way I could get the `Part` instance to which my element belongs to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, given say a `P` object, you can call `getParent()` to find its parent object.

But those objects don't know which part they are associated with.

When you first find your place holders using your `Docx4JPlaceHolderFinder`, you are going to need to record the part in which they are found.  Or change your approach to do the processing part by part.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just iterated over each part, it works great.